# seperate google analytics for mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to have 2 separate google analytic accounts for a website one for mobile and one for desktop.

I have separate code for both but the URL is same.

I would like to know if i can create 2 google analytic account from same URL.
If google allows that, then I can paste js code for 2 accounts in separate  codes.

Comment: i think google analytics already provide statistics about the mobile and desktop

Comment: Yes, but I want to have 2 separate google analytic accounts for mobile and desktop.

Comment: Have you tried creating two google analytics with the same URL?

Comment: yes it doesnt give any error.

Comment: then find out more on the google analytics if what he is doing if visiting through desktop and mobile